# Unable to use Shared Columns from Document Sets in Quick Parts

Tags: document-set, quick-parts

I am trying to use metadata from a document set in a document which is an "Allowed Content Type" document.

The content type has its own site columns which are listed in "Quick Parts" but the columns from the document set are not there.

They are all listed as "Shared columns" in the document set settings.

A simple example is I have a document set with columns Account and Rep.  I want to use Quick Parts to populate these values inside word documents inside the set.

Any ideas?

Comment: When I upload a document, set the CT the shared columns are added.  When I go new document based on the CT they are not populated.

Comment: Same problem here... Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue.  Create your doc set, add your shared columns, then go to the doc set, add a new document of the content type you want (click the new doc pulldown and select your content type).  You will not be able to see your shared columns at this time because they don't exist.  Save the document, then open it up again.  Now go to quick parts and add it.  They should exist now.  Add your quick parts, then save the doc as a template on your computer.  Go back into the doc set and add this new template as the default content.  It should now work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a bug.  All works if you do one of the following

Enable checkin/out for the shared column data to populate when uploading aor adding documents
OR edit metadata in the document set.  This then flows to all doc in that set.

UPDATE: But the metatdata is still not in the DIP so cannot be used in Quick Parts

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure both the document set definition and your Word document content type use the same defined site column data. (For the sake of clarity, let's call your Word document content type a "Customer Order").

In your example with "Account" and "Rep" data, define those types of data as site columns at the site collection level, then make sure your document set and your "Customer Order" content type are defined with those site columns.

Finally, your "Customer Order" content type template - you'll need to re-insert the Quick parts that link to the correct site column data, then re-upload that as your "Customer Order" content type template. Otherwise, it will still point to the old metadata, which isn't linked.

Make sense?